# Are POSIX IO operations read() and write() compatible with DAX file system?

Tags: intel, persistent-memory

I have configured an Intel Optane Persistent memory with the fsdax mode and mounted an ext4-dax filesystem on it. I am trying to read and write to the device using POSIX API `(read() and write())` but I am seeing no performance improvement over writing to the HDD. 
 My guess is that the `read()` and `write()` calls do not bypass the page cache. So my question is do I need to use mmap or the PMDK library to read/write to the PM device?

Comment: Are I/Os "to the HDD" actually just being cached in RAM as well, because you didn't use `fdatasync`?  You're correct that read() and write() don't bypass the pagecache, and normally you don't want them to because that would be super slow.  open(O_DIRECT) could be one way to change that.

Comment: The page cache seems to be the issue. So I executed the commands `echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. Now the read/write bandwidth for both HDD and PM has decreased meaning that memory is not coming into the picture. However the write bandwidth is coming out to be same for both HDD and PM although read bandwidth is higher for the PM. Is this because the POSIX API is still somehow not being able to exploit the direct-access property of the PM?